# Magento is Redirecting to the xampp Dashboard Page

Tags: php, magento

I have created the single store website in Magento. I have edited database file and configured URL in database. I have created virtual host. However the new live site from server is not working properly. The site is being redirected to localhost/dashboard.

Comment: show your vhost config

Comment: 127.0.0.1 furniturestore.com (This is my vhost configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these step first and check

Remove your `var/cache` folder.

Fulsh all cache from admin.

Reindex all from index management

To reindex via command line

1 – Go to ‘`shell`’ folder in your Magento installation:

```
cd shell
```

2 – Execute reindex using this command:

```
php -f indexer.php reindexall
```

also

check your  .htaccess file,you have to  replaced server .htaccess file to Magento default .htaccess file and it works.

Comment: I have tried all these steps but still the site is being redirected to localhost/dashboard.

Comment: check your .htaccess file,you have to replaced server .htaccess file to Magento default .htaccess file and it works.   you have tried this ?

Comment: Yes I have tried this but still the same thing is happening.